# What kind of data structure would I use for this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a class Person, with the fields firstname, lastname, age and zipcode. I need to store a large collection of these Person objects in memory. I need to be able to add and delete items, in addition to being able to sort and search by any of the fields. What data structure and mechanism would I use to accomplish this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @FlorianF. yes only vanilla JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have a class Person, with the fields firstname, lastname, age and zipcode. I need to store a large collection of these Person objects in memory.*

Then an array of object literals

```
[
    {
        firstName: John,
        lastName: Doe,
        age: 23,
        zipcode: 0987
    },{
        firstName: Jane,
        lastName: Doe,
        age: 21,
        zipcode: 0987
    }
]
```

> *I need to be able to add and delete items, in addition to being able to sort and search by any of the fields.*

Array [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), respectively. There are actually more operations than just these basic four.

> *What data structure and mechanism would I use to accomplish this?*

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). They're pretty much all you have for JS. All the rest are improvised structures that use these guys.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of objects.

```
[
    {
        firstName: Bill,
        lastName: Gates
        age: 20
        zipcode: 12345
    }, {
        firstName: Jimm,
        lastName: Winter
        age: 30
        zipcode: 65432
    }
]
```

Also you can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/docs) to work with such collections in elegant way.

Basically this is [JSON](http://www.json.org/) that is universal format of data storing, filtering and transferring.